# NGINX Ingress Controller not working on Amazon EKS

Tags: nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

**NGINX Ingress Controller not working on Amazon EKS**

I created an Amazon EKS cluster on a private subnet using eksctl.

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name eks101 \
--version 1.18 \
--region af-south-1 \
--nodegroup-name standard-workers \
--node-type t3.medium \
--nodes 3 \
--nodes-min 1 \
--nodes-max 4 --managed \
--vpc-private-subnets=subnet-123,subnet-456,subnet-789 \
--node-private-networking
```

I had to tag the private subnets else the load balancer does not get created

```
aws ec2 create-tags \
    --resources subnet-123 subnet-456 subnet-789 \
    --tags Key=kubernetes.io/cluster/eks101,Value=owned   Key=kubernetes.io/role/elb,Value=1
```

I then installed the NGINX Ingress Controller using this installation instructions: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

I installed the Ingress Controller using a Deployment not a DaemonSet

I had to add the following annotation to the loadbalancer-aws-elb.yaml for it to create a load balancer:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Pods and services are all running:

```
# kubectl get pod -n nginx-ingress
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-576565b59c-s9c6b   1/1     Running   0          3h15m

# kubectl get service -n nginx-ingress
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                                        PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   172.20.44.89   internal-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-123456789.af-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:30694/TCP,443:31260/TCP   33s
```

When I connect to the load balancer I get the 404 Not Found, which is correct.

```
curl -k http://internal-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-123456789.af-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
```

I then installed a sample application

```
kubectl apply -f apache-app.yaml

# kubectl get pod
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apache-app-84f76964b5-9c4wc   1/1     Running   0          114s
apache-app-84f76964b5-xvmzx   1/1     Running   0          114s

# kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
apache-app   ClusterIP   172.20.243.80   <none>        80/TCP    24s

# kubectl get ing
NAME         CLASS    HOSTS                 ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
apache-app   <none>   apache.mydomain.com             80      39s

curl -k -H "Host: apache.mydomain.com" http://internal-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-123456789.af-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
```

It is not routing to the application.
Even when I add the apache.mydomain.com host header.
Still get the 404 Not Found.
Same response as when calling with out the host header.
When I look at the nginx-ingress pod logs all I see is this:

```
kubectl get pod -n nginx-ingress
kubectl logs -f --tail 20 $(kubectl get pod -n nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -n nginx-ingress

10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:11:53:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:11:54:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:11:58:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:12:01:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:12:01:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.249.225.11 - - [14/Dec/2020:12:01:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
```

**Where else can I look for the problem?**

If I change my application service to a LoadBalancer instead of using ingress, it works.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: apache-app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I upgrade the apiVersion to `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` then I don't need to specify the ingress controller in my application ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apache-app
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the ingress class is set as the default:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

I still had to specify the ingress class in my application ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apache-app
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```